# Object returning value undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Right now I have an object from my API that looks like this -

```
design: {
    "_id": "5b291367e3d1390d86931b44",
    "name": "PRP15",
    "thickness1": {
      "name": "4/4",
      "price": 12.64
    },
    "thickness2": {
      "name": "5/4",
      "price": 14.99
    },
    "createdAt": "2018-06-19T14:29:59.930Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-07-22T01:30:16.316Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "photo": null,
}
```

when I console log *design.thickness1* i'm returning

```
{name: "4/4", price: 12.64}
```

however when i do *design.thickness1.price* its returning

```
undefined
```

its also doing it if i do *design.thickness2.price*

i have no idea why and nothing im doing seems to be working.  any help would be much appreciated!  i've even tried creating a variable with the same object and it *does* return the correct value

edit: here is how I am currently using it

```
const { design } = this.props

console.log('Design:   ' + JSON.stringify(design, null, 2)); 
//returning
//{
  //"_id": "5b291367e3d1390d86931b44",
  //"name": "PRP15",
  //"thickness1": {
    //"name": "4/4",
    //"price": 12.64
  //},
  //"thickness2": {
    //"name": "5/4",
   //"price": 14.99
  //},
  //"createdAt": "2018-06-19T14:29:59.930Z",
  //"updatedAt": "2018-07-22T01:30:16.316Z",
  //"__v": 0,
  //"photo": null,
//}


console.log('Thickness1 Price:   ' + JSON.stringify(design.thickness1, null, 2));
//returning {name: "4/4", price: 12.64}

console.log('Design Price:   ' + JSON.stringify(design.thickness1.price, null, 2));
//returning undefined



const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  design: state.part_list.designs
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DoorOrders);
```

Comment: Can you share more code, so we can see how you store the object and how you interact with it in the code

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://jsfiddle.net/bwy0ts2m/) You don't have any property named `thickness` so that returns `undefined` and printing `design.thickness1.price` works just fine. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Ivar sorry that was a typo on my part when i posted it here - i am actually console.logging design.thickness1.price

Comment: @JayPray In that case it should indeed print as you say, but `design.thickness1.price` still should work fine. We can't answer your question without more information. Again, please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Ivar just updated my post

Comment: @JayPray I'm still not getting the same result as you suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/kgu9h265/

Comment: `returning undefined` actually, console.log **always returns `undefined`** - I too have copied the code and can not reproduce the issue - perhaps the code in the question is not the code you have an issue with

Answer (score 1):

fixed

basically react was trying to render it before it had a value and was crashing it so i added a conditional

```
if(!designs[0].thickness1){
  return null
}else{
  console.log('Design Price:   ' + (JSON.stringify(designs[0].thickness1.price)));
  console.log(typeof (designs[0].thickness1.price));
}
```